# I have been a long time not going there

Tags: grammar

I have been a long time not going there.

I have around 5 years no going there, can we say "I have been a long time not going there."

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for basic questions such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider saying instead:

> *I haven't been there for a long time*.
>
> *I haven't been there for around five years*.

Or

> *I haven't been there in a long time*.
>
> *I haven't been there in around five years*.

Or

> *It's [=it has] been a long time since I haven't been there*.
>
> *It's been around five years since I haven't been there*.

Or

> *It's been a long time since I (last) went there*.
>
> *It's been around five years since I (last) went there*.